# How to create a cyclic iterator over the alphabet in Python?

Tags: python

Given the following scenario:

```
import string

UPPERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

How to create a cyclic loop over the alphabet jumping N positions?

---

**Example 1**:

**letter** = a, **jump** = 5

**Result**: f

---

**Example 2**:

**letter** = z, **jump** = 5

**Result**: e

---

So far, I got:

```
import string

UPPERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

def forward(letter, jump):
    alphabet = LOWERCASE_ALPHABET if letter.islower() else UPPERCASE_ALPHABET
    index = alphabet.index(letter)
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count == jump:
            return alphabet[index]

        if index == len(alphabet):            
            index = 0

        index += 1
        count += 1

print forward('a', 5)
print forward('z', 5)
```

But it doesn't look Pythonic at all...

Is there a better and Pythonic way of doing this? Maybe using chr(ord('N') + position) ?

Comment: If you make your alphabet variables contain two sequential copies of the alphabet, then you easily "wrap around" when you reach the end of the alphabet.

Comment: @kindall got it! Maybe itertools.cycle() and itertools.islice() could help here...

Comment: Watch out - `islice`-ing with a step has to individually discard all the skipped elements. It can't efficiently jump to the index it needs. That might not matter much for small steps, but it's important to keep in mind for larger steps or for more expensive underlying iterators.

Comment: There is a defect: `forward('z', 1)`

Comment: @DavidCullen oops, you're right! There's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had the right idea with `ord` and `chr`:

```
import string

def forward(letter, jump):
    if letter.islower():
        start_character = ord('a')
    else:
        start_character = ord('A')
    start = ord(letter) - start_character
    offset = ((start + jump) % 26) + start_character
    result = chr(offset)
    return result

print forward('a', 5)
print forward('z', 5)
print forward('z', 1)
print forward('a', 26)
print forward('A', 5)
print forward('Z', 5)
print forward('Z', 1)
print forward('A', 26)
```

**Output**

```
f
e
a
a
F
E
A
A
```

Comment: The geek style, you kill it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a custom iterator class to encapsulate `itertools.cycle()` and provide a `skip()` functionality, e.g.:

```
import itertools

class CyclicSkipIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterator = itertools.cycle(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):  # use __next__ on Python 3.x
        return next(self._iterator)

    def skip(self, number=1):
        for i in xrange(number):  # use range() on Python 3.x
            next(self._iterator)
```

Then you can do exactly what you wanted with it:

```
import string

LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

lower_iter = CyclicSkipIterator(LOWERCASE_ALPHABET)
print(next(lower_iter))  # a
lower_iter.skip(4)  # skip next 4 letters: b, c, d, e
print(next(lower_iter))  # f
lower_iter.skip(19)  # skip another 19 letters to arrive at z
print(next(lower_iter))  # z
lower_iter.skip(4)  # skip next 4 letters: a, b, c, d
print(next(lower_iter))  # e
```

You can add even more functionality if you wanted to, like reversing, switching iterables mid-iteration etc.

**UPDATE**: If you want to jump to a specific element in the list, you can add a method for that to the `CyclicSkipIterator`:

```
class CyclicSkipIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterator = itertools.cycle(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):  # use __next__ on Python 3.x
        return next(self._iterator)

    def skip(self, number=1):
        for _ in range(number):  # use range() on Python 3.x
            next(self._iterator)

    def skip_to(self, element, max_count=100):  # max_count protects against endless cycling
        max_count = max(1, max_count)  # ensure at least one iteration
        for _ in range(max_count):  # use range() on Python 3.x
            e = next(self._iterator)
            if element == e:
                break
```

Then you can skip_to whatever letter you want:

```
import string

LOWERCASE_ALPHABET = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

lower_iter = CyclicSkipIterator(LOWERCASE_ALPHABET)
print(next(lower_iter))  # a
lower_iter.skip(4)  # skip 4 letters: b, c, d, e
print(next(lower_iter))  # f
lower_iter.skip_to("y")  # skip all letters up to y
print(next(lower_iter))  # z
lower_iter.skip(4)  # skip 4 letters: a, b, c, d
print(next(lower_iter))  # e
```

Comment: You need to provide a way to specify the starting letter.

Comment: @DavidCullen - OP asked only for jumping, but fair enough, I'll update...

Comment: Hey @zwer thanks for the answer, this is another way to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
class CyclicIterator:
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.lst=lst
        self.i=0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        result=self.lst[self.i % len(self.lst)]
        self.i+=3   #increasing by 3
        return result
```

class that has **iter**() and **next**() meets iterator protocol. creating an instance of this iterator class

```
iter_cycle=CyclicIterator('abcdefghiijklmnnoprstuvyz')

numbers=range(1,27,3) # 26 letters increases by 3
list(zip(list(numbers),iter_cycle))
```

[image]